# How to access sqlite database which already exists in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created an sqlite databse and put it into the assets folder. How can I access it? I have created a database helper class also, but my data is "not taking the path".

Plz help me

Thanks

Comment: Please double-check your spelling before submitting a question. Also what do you mean your "data is not taking the path"? What path? Provide specifics!

Answer (score 1):

Copy your database file from `/asset` to internal databases directory `/data/data/<package_name>/databases/`, then use that database file.

Look at this SO question [How to ship an Android application with a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database).

Also this tutorial [Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)